# HTTPS via Proxy

Tags: proxy, https

There is a secure webpage in server A, which I need to access from internet. However server A wont allow connection from all clients(my ip needs to be whitelisted) hence I got the IP of my slicehost slice whitelisted. Now I want to access the page in server A via my slicehost from my home and office PCs(through web browser). How do I do this. Can this slice work like a proxy and route the request from home PC to server A. The connection to server A is HTTPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your slicehost service supports SSH, you could setup an SSH tunnel between your local machine and slicehost, then configure your web browser to use that tunnel as a SOCKS5 proxy.  You don't specify what OS you're running locally, but I'm going to presume windows.

Here's a tutorial:

http://thinkhole.org/wp/2006/05/10/howto-secure-firefox-and-im-with-putty/